# npm ERR! cb() never called! while running npm install for spring boot admin sample custom ui

Tags: npm, npm-install, spring-boot-admin

I am running npm install in spring boot admin custom ui `git` project and `npm ERR! cb()` never called!.
Kindly guide me what will be the possibility of this error and how to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: You can try running the command `npm cache clean`. Can you share the error logs here and which version of npm are you using. Use `npm -v` to check the version.

Comment: Tried doing the same, still getting the same issue